# OpenXava Change background color of one single row

Tags: css, openxava

I need to change the background color of one single row in one table in Openxava, e.g. the whole row with field where `status = resolved` should turn green or a row where the `date field = currentDate` should turn yellow.

Until now I changed the background color in `custom.css` and experimented with `naviox.css,` but it only changed the background color of the whole list `.ox-list`.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use @RowStyle annotation directly on the defined collection:

```
@RowStyle(style = "row-highlight-rates", property = "notEqual", value = "true")
private List<Rate> rates;
```

On the custom.css I add the row-highlight-xxx :

```
tr.row-highlight-rates{
    background-color: #e37d6f;
}

tr.row-highlight-rates:hover {
  background-color: #d94b37;
}
```